# Как имплементировать tree в Java?

Tags: java, структуры-данных, дерево, data-structures

Проблема такова:

У меня есть три List:

```
List<String> origins; //10 элементов
List<String> destinations;  //10 элементов
List<String> distances;     //100 элементов
```

Задача моя соединить их всех в одну структуру. Структура такова:

1 -> 10 -> 10

То есть, каждый элемент в origins по отдельности должен быть связан со всеми 10 элементов из destinations. То бишь 1 origin - 10 destinations - (0,10) distances, 2 origin - 10 destinations - (10,20) distances, 3 origin - (20,30) destinations ...

Мне кажется это выглядит как Tree data structure, хотя я пробовал и Hashmap, но что-то не выходит.

Также вопрос, могу ли я использовать Lists как root или оно должно быть string, то есть одним значение?

```
root (List<String> origins)
|
List<String> destinations -0 |  List<String> destinations -1| List<String> destinations -2... -10
|
List<String> distances (0,10)| List<String> distances (10,20)| List<String> distances (20,30) ...(90,100)
```

Вот что я попробовал сделать c помошью HashMap:

```
for ( Map.Entry<List<String>, Map<List<String>, List<String>>> entry : mapMap.entrySet()) {
        List<String> key = entry.getKey(); //origins
        Map<List<String>, List<String>> tab = entry.getValue(); //destinations and distances
        // do something with key and/or tab
        System.out.println(key.toString() + " " + tab.toString());
    }
```

или

```
Map<List<String>,List<String>> map1 = new LinkedHashMap<>();  // ordered
    Map<List<String>,Map<List<String>,List<String>>> map2 = new LinkedHashMap<>();  // ordered
    map1.put(placesDestinations, placeDistances);
    map2.put(placesOrigins, map1);
```

Оба результата, не выводят, так как мне нужно. Что происходит, это просто выводит первый лист origins, потом destinations, а затем все distances.

Comment: `хотя я пробовал и Hashmap, но что-то не выходит` поконкретнее и с кодом пожалуйста

Comment: Поправил, надеюсь сейчас легче понять =)

Comment: в дереве, если вы его нарисуете на бумажке, увидите, что там один элемент может иметь несколько потомков. Вы же тут `Map<List<String>,List<String>>` пытаетесь свядать список со списком, что в терминах дерева смысла не имеет. Попробуте вместо связи `список-список`, сделать связь `элемент-список`.

Comment: @Marin С конца можно сделать, сначала **Map**, у которого ключ `destinations` а значение `distances`. А потом ещё один `map`, у которого ключ `origins`, а значение предыдущий **Map**

Comment: @АлексейОсецкий если значения строк все разные (как и должно быть в дереве), то можно и одной HashMap обойтись. + значения лучше хранить в HashSet, чтобы гарантировать, что не будет дублирования в значениях

Comment: Я бы это оформил классами, поскольку между origins и destinations вообще нет никакой связи и по сути неважно, какой из origins вы в итоге выберете. А вот вторая связь легко описывается через подсписок на типа `distances.subList(destinations.indexOf(element)*10, destinations.indexOf(element)*10 + 10);`, который легко оформить в виде функции.

Comment: Как нет связи между origins и destinations?) На каждую origin приходится 10 destination. Их очередность, не меняется.

Comment: Значения могут дублироваться, HashSet не нужен

Comment: Я же правильно понял, что в каждом origin находятся одни и те же destination в кол-ве 10 штук?

Comment: вообще, по сути задачи, у вас не дерево, а двухкомпонентный взвешанный граф, где с одной стороны стоят вершины origins, с противоположной - вершины destinations, и эти вершины связаны ребрами distances - ребра с указанием длины дистанции

Comment: Правильно, но на счет sublist - ов я поспорю, так как это не то, чего я хочу. По суть мне нужно Matrix где row and columns Origins и destinations, а значия будут distances

Comment: почему бы тогда не сделать матрицу?

Comment: @Marin, ну не знаю, посмотрите, может всё-таки зайдет: https://pastebin.com/P67864tx если я правильно понял задачу конечно.

Comment: смотриться хорошо, но вот эта строка возвращает nullPointerException: //Непосредвенно используем
        List<Distances> valueDistances = root.get("o2").get("d5").distances;
        System.out.println("Hello world" + valueDistances.toString());

Comment: Можете поправить код где Java 8 лямбда используется и поменять на Java 7? Моя версия Анроида не подерживает 8

Comment: @Marin, да, там тогда надо просто лямбды на цикл заменить. Можете либо взять измененные get, либо полностью эту новую реализацию: я там просто спрятал в конструктор инициализации и добавил геттеры и сеттеры: https://pastebin.com/04NtTFqh Если все хорошо, тогда скажите и я оформлю это ответом.

Comment: Проблему полностью, не решили, но дали много подсказок. Я приму, как ответ очень близко, к тому что мне нужно. Можете оформлять)  Если можете, то было бы хорошо если лямбды на циклы сменили. Спасибо!

Comment: @Marin, я добавил пример для реализации на простых коллекциях, которую вы хотели сделать и пример с англоязычного SO с правильной и полной реализацией дерева. Посмотрите, может будет так же интересно.

Comment: Спасибо за советы и примеры, очень кстати!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если строить дерево на каких-то простых структурах, то нужно использовать Map, так как дерево имеет одно ключевое значение и несколько дочерних. Поскольку в данном случае мы работает с `String`, это будет множество вида `Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, .... >>>>`. Работать с такой структурой без какой-либо оболочки достаточно затруднительно.

Поскольку у нас конечное кол-во вариантов и дерево ограничено тремя уровнями, его можно построить так начиная с конца:

```
    Map<String, List<String>> destinationMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
    for(int i = 0; i < destinations.size(); i++) {
        destinationMap.put(destinations.get(i), distances.subList(i*10, i*10 + 10));
    }
    Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>>  originsMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Map<String, List<String>>>();
    for(int i = 0; i < origins.size(); i++) {
        originsMap.put(origins.get(i), destinationMap);
    }
    List<String> distanceList = originsMap.get("o5").get("d3");
```

Получается своеобразное дерево. Мы получим в качестве ключа `String`, а в качестве потомков `Map<String, List<String>>` и `List<String>` на втором и третьем уровне дерева соответственно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если бы дерево было больше, то задача бы усложнилась. Поэтому как по мне легче такие вещи строить на классах, которые включают друг друга:

```
class Node {
    private String key;
    private Node parent;
    private List<Node> childs;
}
```

Ну или так, если делать полную и правильную реализацию: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19330731/tree-implementation-in-java-root-parents-and-children

В данном случае достаточно будет такой структуры на классах:

```
public class Root {

    private List<Origin> origins;

    public Origin get(String name) {
        for(Origin origin : origins)
            if(origin.getName().equals(name))
                return origin;
        return null;
    }

    public Root(List<String> origins, List<String> destinations, List<String> distances ) {
        List<Destination> destinationList = new ArrayList<Destination>();
        for(int i = 0; i < destinations.size(); i++) {
            destinationList.add(new Destination(destinations.get(i), distances.subList(i*10, i*10 + 10)));
        }

        List<Origin> originsList = new ArrayList<Origin>();
        for(int i = 0; i < origins.size(); i++) {
            originsList.add(new Origin(origins.get(i), destinationList));
        }

        this.origins = originsList;
    }

    public List<Origin> getOrigins() {
        return origins;
    }

    public void setOrigins(List<Origin> origins) {
        this.origins = origins;
    }
}

public class Origin {
    private String name;
    private List<Destination> destinations;

    public Destination get(String name) {
        for(Destination destination : destinations)
            if(destination.getName().equals(name))
                return destination;
        return null;
    }

    public Origin(String name, List<Destination> destinations) {
        this.name = name;
        this.destinations = destinations;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Destination> getDestinations() {
        return destinations;
    }

    public void setDestinations(List<Destination> destinations) {
        this.destinations = destinations;
    }
}

public class Destination {
    private String name;
    private List<Distance> distances = new ArrayList<Distance>();

    public Distance get(String name) {
        for(Distance distance : distances)
            if(distance.getName().equals(name))
                return distance;
        return null;
    }

    public Destination(String name, List<String> distances) {
        this.name = name;
        for(String el : distances)
            this.distances.add(new Distance(el));
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Distance> getDistances() {
        return distances;
    }

    public void setDistances(List<Distance> distances) {
        this.distances = distances;
    }
}

public class Distance {
    private String name;

    public Distance(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> origins = Arrays.asList("o1", "o2", "o3", "o4", "o5", "o6", "o7", "o8", "o9", "o10");
        List<String> destinations = Arrays.asList("d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5", "d6", "d7", "d8", "d9", "d10");
        List<String> distances = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
                "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20",
                "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30",
                "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40",
                "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50",
                "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60",
                "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70",
                "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80",
                "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90",
                "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100");


        Root root = new Root(origins, destinations, distances);
        List<Distance> distanceList = root.get("o2").get("d5").getDistances();

        System.out.println(distanceList.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Очень интересно объясняете! Спасибо большое!